# java hashmap key iteration

Tags: java, iteration, hashmap

Is there any way to iterate through a java Hashmap and print out all the values for every key that is a part of the Hashmap?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With *[for-each loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)*, use [`Map.keySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) for iterating keys, [`Map.values()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) for iterating values and [`Map.entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) for iterating key/value pairs.

Note that all these are direct views to the map that was used to acquire them so any modification you make to any of the three or the map itself will reflect to all the others too.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you do this by getting the `entrySet()` of the map. For example:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// ...

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

(Ofcourse, replace `String` and `Object` with the types that your particular `Map` has - the code above is just an example).

Answer (score 4):

```
public class abcd {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Map<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        testMap.put(10, "a");
        testMap.put(20, "b");
        testMap.put(30, "c");
        testMap.put(40, "d");
        for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
            Integer key=entry.getKey();
            String value=entry.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Map.Entry<T,U> e : map.entrySet())
{
    T key = e.getKey();
    U value = e.getValue();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In addition, if you use a LinkedHashMap as the implementation, you'll iterate in the order the key/value pairs were inserted.  If that's not important, use a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

```
hashmap.keySet().iterator()
```

use a `for` loop to iterate it.

then use `hashmap.get(item)` to get individual values,

Alternatively just use `entrySet()` for getting an iterator for values.

Comment: Or, depending on what ping means by "values", `hashmap.values().iterator()`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, please:

```
HashMap<String,String> HeyHoLetsGo = new HashMap();

HeyHoLetsGo.put("I", "wanna be your dog");
HeyHoLetsGo.put("Sheena", "is a punk rocker");
HeyHoLetsGo.put("Rudie", "can't fail");

for ( String theKey : HeyHoLetsGo.keySet() ){
    System.out.println(theKey + " "+HeyHoLetsGo.get(theKey));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 added [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) which you can use like this:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key=" + k + " value=" + v));
```

There's also [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.BiFunction)) if you want to update the values:

```
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> {
    int newValue = v + 1;
    System.out.println("key=" + k + " value=" + v + " new value=" + newValue);
    return newValue;
});
```