# Print all keys in a LinkedHashMap in Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` in my code:

```
 protected LinkedHashMap<String, String> profileMap;
```

I want to print all the keys present in `profileMap`.  How can do this using an `Iterator` or a loop?

Comment: seems to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344734/java-hashmap-key-iteration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should iterate over the `Set` from [`Map.keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29):

```
for (final String key : profileMap.keySet()) {
  /* print the key */
}
```

Using an `Iterator` explicitly,

```
final Iterator<String> cursor = profileMap.keySet().iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  final String key = cursor.next();
  /* print the key */
}
```

Both are more or less identical when compiled, however.

Comment: You can get rid of all the finals. Also for the Iterator you can also use a for loop (better since it limits the scope of `cursor`).

Comment: @SteveKuo of course you can remove the `final`, but I see no reason why -- especially if only printing the keys. If for whatever reason he needs the fields to be mutable he can remove `final`, as this is a mere template.

Comment: @user268397 since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can Iterate Through the `Map Entries` and you can choose to print `e.getKey()` or `e.getValue()` according to your choice.

```
   for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
    }
```

Comment: but if you are only interested in keys... just use the keySet()