# How to print the text

Tags: java, string

```
public class usermain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String test = "cat=\"dog\"; + abc=\"bcd\"; ";

        System.out.println(test);   


    // split on ':' and on '::'
    String[] parts = test.split("");

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
        map.put(parts[i], parts[i + 1]);
    }

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}

}
```

I want to display in an array:

```
[cat] = dog
[abc] = bcd
```

Comment: You can just replace semicolon and plus sign with empty string, no need to split.

Comment: i want to print like cat =dog and abc =bcd in an array

Comment: In final for-loop give more appropriate name to "String s" e.g. "String key" that makes it easier for you to understand what this value in the string is. Then in the same for-loop print out "key" (not map) and further more, you should later print "map.get(key)" (this returns value associated with key)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class usermain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "cat=\"dog\"; + abc=\"bcd\"; ";

        System.out.println(test);   


    String[] parts = test.split(" + ");

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
        System.out.println("[" + parts.replace (';','').replace ("=","]="));
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a value in a proper format to split it and then you can print both key and value using entrySet()

Refer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344768/3496666

String test = "cat=\"dog\"; + abc=\"bcd\"; ";

For the above string, first replace double quotes, semi colon, spaces and other characters except '+' into empty character

then split the string with '+' as string array and then split by '=' for each string in a string array. Now you can display the output as expected using entrySet()